# Saving files on shared folder removes all permissions

Tags: network-shares, windows-server

We have a shared on a windows 2019 server. If a user has the shared map as a network drive and then open a file and overwrite it. All permissions to that files are removed. Parent folder has Permission and "Enabled inheritance" set.

[image]

Comment: Which operating system is used by that user? Does it happen with other users?

Comment: @harrymc all windows computers (10 and 11) . Happens for multiple users. Sometimes you can save the file once or twice but then suddenly permissions are gone.

Has happen by creating folders manually, copying files to that folder, as well as using third party software (microsoft excel, libreoffice, keypass).

Comment: Is it possible that the file is locked by some user ?

Comment: @harrymc The only user that is accessing/saving the file is me testing. I can easily reproduce the problem with files only added/changed by me.

Comment: Is there something special about the shared folder on the server side?

Comment: anything I should look out for in terms of "special".
Under Sharing:
It has a network path and shared with out domain users. Read/write permission level.

Under "advanced sharing" it is enabled with a name. Full control permissions for domain users and administrators. "read" for "Everyone".

The only "odd" thing I know is that you cant access the share by
\\servername\sharename

You HAVE to do "map network drive" otherwise the folder looks empty, but that is maybe how stuff works?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you ever discover the cause in your case?

Comment: @Tanj in this intance, if I remember correctly, it was when saving files in Libreoffice . Could never find a way to fix it other than "use excel" or copy the files locally, change and then copy them back.